# SUMIFS with OR criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to write a sum function for all entries in a certain month (>= start of month, < eomonth + 1) where a certain field has one of several values.

(For example: All entries in July, where project = Project A or project = Project B)

So far, I've been using `SUMIFS`, but I can't figure out how to get the `OR` criterion in.

Example:

```
SUMIFS(E:E, C:C, ">="&B6, C:C, "<"&EOMONTH(B6, 0)+1, G:G, "=Project A“, A:A, "=Person B”)
```

The B column holds a particular month as a date. I'd like to use the `OR` criterion on people (e.g. `"=Person B" OR "=Person C"`).

Comment: What's an example of a formula you've been using?

Comment: =SUMIFS(E:E, C:C, ">="&B6, C:C, "<"&EOMONTH(B6, 0)+1, G:G, "=Project A“, A:A, "=Person B”)

Comment: The B column holds a particular month as a date, I'd like to use the OR criterion on people (e.g. "=Person B" OR "=Person C")

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem:

Rather than using `SUMIFS`, I'm using a `SUM` of `QUERY`:

`=SUM(QUERY(A:G,"Select E where A matches '"&Join("|","Person A", "Person B", "Person C")&"' and G='Project A' and toDate(C) >= date '"
& text(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and toDate(C) < date '" &
text(EOMONTH(B2, 0)+1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' "))`

The conditional part being `where A matches '"&Join("|","Person A", "Person B", "Person C")&"'`.